# Latexmk exit code 12 in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, latexmk

I'm trying to run a test script in an azure devops pipeline. I have a test that runs on my own environment but fails in the pipeline.

when I run the following code:

```
command = '['latexmk', '-pdf', '--interaction=nonstopmode', '/tmp/my_tex.tex']'
output = subprocess.check_output(command,
                                                 stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                                 **check_output_kwargs)
```

Locally it finishes without errors. When I run it in the DevOps pipeline I get:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: 
Command '['latexmk', '-pdf', '--interaction=nonstopmode', '/tmp/tmp78wpkv3l/Unknown.tex']' 
returned non-zero exit status 12.
```

Which isn't very descriptive. Does anybody know how to solve this or get more descriptive error messages?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that `latexmk` was being run in the wrong folder, fixed with a simple `os.chdir(<correct folder>)`